# configure: error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt

Tags: compiling, php, suse

I'm trying to compile php on Suse 10.2. When I run the configure script with --with-mcrypt I receive this message:

> configure: error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt

Comment: Have you tried installing that package?

Comment: Sure did. both, mcrypt and libmcrypt where  previously installed via yast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSUSE 10.2 has been EOL since 11-30-2008. I recommend updating to a supported version like 15.1 or 42.3.

If you insist on using what you have then you'll have to build the package from source like you're doing with PHP. You will then prepend its binary and library directories to your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

If you use a supported version then you can just use `zypper` to install php and any other packages because as it stands right now, you're going to have to build everything from source that isn't on that DVD.

Comment: package 'libmcrypt-devel' not found

Comment: I'm using OpenSuSE 10.2 from an DVD ISO as installation source  openSUSE-10.2-GM-DVD-x86_64.iso

Comment: @Mauricio Then you to add that information to your question. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

In case you still need it, it may help

```
yum install epel-release
yum install libmcrypt-devel
```

Ref: https://www.omniweb.com/wordpress/?p=1285